# Cisco 93180LC licensing question

Tags: nx-os

We have two cisco n9k-c93180lc-ex and we enabled bgp and pbr feature and it showed the following error

```
%LICMGR-2-LOG_LIC_MISSING_WARNING: A feature that requires LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES_PKG license is not installed. Syst
em supports honor based licensing so feature will continue to be fully functional. Use 'show license usage <package-name>' to find features using missing lice
nse.
```

what does this mean?

- I can use these feature without any limitation on time or ... the only things that i can not use is cisco support?

`show license usage` shows this output to me:

```
show license usage
Feature                      Ins  Lic   Status Expiry Date Comments
                                 Count
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACI-STRG                      No    -   Unused             -
ACI-AD-GF                     No    -   Unused             -
ACI-AD-XF                     No    -   Unused             -
ACI-ES-GF                     No    -   Unused             -
ACI-ES-XF                     No    -   Unused             -
ACI-AD-XF2                    No    -   Unused             -
ACI-ES-XF2                    No    -   Unused             -
ACI-SEC-GF                    No    -   Unused             -
ACI-SEC-XF                    No    -   Unused             -
ACI-SEC-XM                    No    0   Unused             -
N9K_LIC_1G                    No    -   Unused             -
VPN_FABRIC                    No    -   Unused             -
ACI-STRG-GF                   No    -   Unused             -
ACI-STRG-XF                   No    -   Unused             -
NXOS_OE_PKG                   No    -   Unused             -
FCOE_NPV_PKG                  No    -   Unused             -
SECURITY_PKG                  No    0   Unused             -
ACI-PREMIER-GF                No    -   Unused             -
ACI-PREMIER-XF                No    -   Unused             -
N9K_UPG_EX_10G                No    -   Unused             -
ACI-PREMIER-XF2               No    -   Unused             -
NXOS-PREMIER-M4               No    -   Unused             -
TP_SERVICES_PKG               No    -   Unused             -
NXOS-PREMIER-M816             No    -   Unused             -
NXOS_ADVANTAGE_GF             No    -   Unused             -
NXOS_ADVANTAGE_M4             No    -   Unused             -
NXOS_ADVANTAGE_XF             No    -   Unused             -
NXOS_ESSENTIALS_GF            No    -   Unused             -
NXOS_ESSENTIALS_M4            No    -   Unused             -
NXOS_ESSENTIALS_XF            No    -   Unused             -
NXOS_ESSENTIALS_XM            No    -   Unused             -
SAN_ENTERPRISE_PKG            No    -   Unused             -
PORT_ACTIVATION_PKG           No    0   Unused             -
NETWORK_SERVICES_PKG          No    -   Unused             -
NXOS_ADVANTAGE_M8-16          No    -   Unused             -
NXOS_ESSENTIALS_M8-16         No    -   Unused             -
FC_PORT_ACTIVATION_PKG        No    0   Unused             -
LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES_PKG   No    -   In use             Honor Start 7H 59M
```

Why there is a counter in description field of LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES_PKG? is it just informational ?

Can somebody help me on this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*Honor based* means that there's no technical enforcement when you activate the license (by activation key or similar). Cisco trusts that you only activate a license that you've paid. Most likely, the license situation is checked when you contact support.

The license count means that you can activate more than one license per chassis/stack - depending on the license and platform they are consumed by chassis, module, port, or similar.

Comment: I see a timer in the output of "show license usages" in the comments field, so it is just informational and there is no technical limitation?

Comment: A license may be unlimited in time (=lifetime of the switch) or expire after a certain period. Currently, it looks like the LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES is in trial/licensed mode and enters honor-based mode in 8 hours.

Comment: i see the timer is just increasing and it is not decreasing, so is it lifetime? it showing this : Feature                      Ins  Lic   Status Expiry Date Comments
                                 Count
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES_PKG   No    -   In use             Honor Start 12H 0M

Comment: Then it's that way around. ;-)

Comment: hmm... so it is unlimited and lifetime just as trust base now?

Comment: also, is it same for nxos 10.3? it seems nxos 10.3 licensing model changed

Comment: You really *should* license what you use, so asking if you *could* without paying is becoming somewhat off topic...

Comment: it is lab and i was just curious it is not about using it without paying.